# I need the input of the user to not skip the value 100

Tags: java

I'm currently working on a program for an O Level project where I have chosen to make a class management system. In my method class, I have various methods which control different functions of my program, such as one which collects the name of the students or one which displays a histogram of the student's grades. However, I have discovered a flaw in one of my methods. This is the method that lists the names of the students, one by one (which are saved in an array from a method that is executed before this method) and asks for the students marks. Here, the user is able to enter any number, which is inconvenient, considering that numerical grades normally range from 0-100. I have tried the following code but I have reached a predicament. The code does in fact stop the user from entering a mark over 100, but instead of allowing the user to re-enter a correct mark, it skips over to the next student, leaving the previous student without a mark. The following is said code:

```
//mark input
public void markin() {
    System.out.println("=====================================");
    System.out.println("Please enter the mark of the students");
    System.out.println("=====================================");
    for (int g = 0; g != marks.length; g++) {
        System.out.println(names[g]);
        marks[g] = Keyboard.readInt();
        while(marks[g]<0||marks[g]>100){
            System.out.println("Kindly enter a number that is less than 100");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Help would be very much appreciated and thank you in advance :)
Apologies if my English is not very good.

Comment: Two issues that I can see...you break the infinite loop you need to actually ask for input, and I can only presume `readInt` is analogous to `nextInt` from `Scanner` which doesn't really work if you hit "Enter" and then enter a new value for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it - you need to read in your while-loop instead of breaking without reading. Also a do-loop would be more appropriate for not having to set an initial invalid value.

```
//mark input
public void markin() {
    System.out.println("=====================================");
    System.out.println("Please enter the mark of the students");
    System.out.println("=====================================");
    for (int g = 0; g != marks.length; g++) {
        System.out.println(names[g]);
        do {
           System.out.println("Kindly enter a number that is less than 100");
           marks[g] = Keyboard.readInt();
        } while(marks[g]<0||marks[g]>100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you're a lifesaver ;)

Answer (score 0):

Set marks[ g ]  to a number that isn't allowed before the loop, like - 1 then check the keyboard input inside of the while loop, 
(and set It there every time as long as the while loop isn't stopped, 
marks[g] = Keyboard.readInt();

and don't  break the loop, as the loop would end anyways when the input is valid

Answer (score 0):

The valid answers has to get into the array sequentially.
Use this simple trick to reset index [g] to the previous value 
then you will overwrite the marks[g] value until you get a valid one:

```
    while(marks[g]<0||marks[g]>100){
        System.out.println("Kindly enter a number that is less than 100");
        g--; // Resetting index to previous value
        break;
    }
```

Comment: If you use this solution there is no need for a while and break, just use an if-clause ;)